# Update isBrowser value when switching from Browser view using react-device-detect library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-device-detect` library in my project, when I switch browser view to mobile view the value of isBrowser give me always the same..
How can I update it every time I switched the view type..

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.resize = this.resize.bind( this );
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize )
    this.resize();
  }
...
  resize(){
    let { isBrowser } = require("react-device-detect");
    console.log( isBrowser );
  }
}
```